# PhD planning concern

Tags: phd

I'm in my third year of PhD. However, I'm still bad at planning. I find myself spending more time on things that are not part of my PhD. For example, I may read books such as self help books and not read papers that are more important for my Phd.

How can I handle this and overcome it?

Answer (score 2):

There's a logically correct but kind of silly answer, which is... focus on getting better with planning. Carve out some time where you will focus on your PhD studies. Spend a half hour or something in the morning with a cup of coffee planning all the things you will do, critically evaluate whether that thing does or does not help you on your PhD, and then *stick to your plan* as closely as possible. Unexpected tasks can come up, but don't let yourself get lost on tangents that aren't related to your work. It isn't always easy to be self-disciplined, but it is achievable if you take it seriously and don't accept excuses from yourself.

If you find the above paragraph insightful, and you're able to implement the suggestions and it fixes your woes, then I guess that's all that needs to be said.

However... I suspect you already know this, and I wonder if the behavior you are seeing is really a symptom of a deeper issue. Why aren't you motivated to work on your PhD tasks? Are you happy? When did this behavior start? There are many resources online for struggling PhD students, for example articles [like this one](https://thesiswhisperer.com/2012/05/08/the-valley-of-shit/) or [this one](https://sauvik-das.medium.com/the-shape-of-your-ph-d-426975399d88) where PhD students describe common feelings where you may recognize things you are going through; online support groups ([here](https://www.online-phd-degrees.com/online-support-groups-phd-students/) is an example -- I am not vouching for this site in particular, but just to show there are groups you can find online). If you have people you are close with in your program or lab, or if you feel safe discussing with your advisor, you can try talking to them.

Regardless of what else you try, I strongly recommend that you also seek out the help of a mental health professional. (So strongly I am putting this into a new paragraph). At least in the US where I went to school, most universities have on-campus mental health resources where you can see a counsellor at no cost to you. In my opinion, understanding and dealing with underlying issues is more likely to get to the root of what's going on, than telling yourself to "plan better."